# Search over queries needed

Tags: feature-request, search, data-explorer

We've got enough in "everything", at least, to want to search for specific queries.

E.g. I know I had some 'queries' that just PRINTed stuff, with no result sets, that would have been useful to test given your comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53277/something-wrong-when-getting-cached-results-i-think). <sub>(Of course it would have been faster to type in new `PRINT` queries, but that wouldn't have necessarily tested the cached queries.)</sub>

It would to be useful to have `inquery:` and `incomment:` qualifiers.

I understand most queries for many SQL keywords would produce lots of results, but if the search results were displayed in a manner very similar to the current browse lists they would still be manageable and useful, especially if the results could be ordered by date as well as some of the other orderings already available for browsing.

If I could think of a good syntax to mean any order^, I'd suggest the default search means in the order given.
I.e. searching for `select from where` could be implemented as `like '%select%from%where%'` (except it should probably consider word boundaries).

^ Perhaps `(` `)` could be used to signify any order, so `( world hello )` will match `PRINT 'Hello, world'`

Comment: can you expand this a bit to explain how you think this should work? Search is really hard cause there is massive overlap

Comment: Now that [Google search works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54961) this is not as needed. E.g. I was able to find [Non-ISO WITH usage](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22group+by+%2a+with%22+site:odata.stackexchange.com). It doesn't yet find any ISO-compatible [ROLLUP](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22group+by+ROLLUP%22+site:odata.stackexchange.com) or [CUBE](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22group+by+CUBE%22+site:odata.stackexchange.com) uses but sooner or later it should find [mine](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/265).

Answer (score 1):

Since 2010 a few new version of SEDE has been deployed and in the topbar there is now a search field.

[image: search field in left topbar]

The search itself is a pretty basic SQL query over the internal table QuerySet

[This](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/QuerySetController.cs#L357) is how your search term is used:

```csharp
builder.Where(@"  qs.Title LIKE @search 
               OR qs.[Description] LIKE @search", 
        new { search = '%' + searchCriteria.SearchTerm + '%' });
```

Notice that you can only search in the query Title or query Description. The SQL itself is not searchable. Your suggestion to implement it as a LIKE is followed so using % or _ or even [A-Z] in the search term behave the same as if you use those patterns in a normal TSQL [LIKE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement.

Additionally there is the `isfeatured:1` search option which will limit the results to only queries that are marked as *featured*. It seems a bit wonky but searching for [isfeatured:1 finder](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=isfeatured%3A1+finder) will return a handful results. Removing the `isfeatured:1` returns way more queries.

Only SEDE admins can flip the featured bit on existing queries.

See also my answer on [keywords search on SEDE might need improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344746)