# How can I search StackExchange Data Explorer?

Tags: support, search, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Search on Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67660/search-on-stack-exchange-data-explorer)

I just noticed that there is no search box on Data Explorer. I guess there should be one in the pipeline. Am I correct?

Also surprising is that Google has not yet indexed the site, so basically there is no way to search the site right now:

[The site went live on June 13th, 2010.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/) Is it normal to take so long before being indexed by Google or the problem is something else entirely?

Comment: May be because robots.txt is inaccessible? http://odata.stackexchange.com/robots.txt

Comment: I'm going to fix that robots file today, oops

Comment: The bit about Google and the robots.txt is new, but the original request for search is a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53545/search-over-queries-needed).

Comment: @Mark Hurd: I was only looking for a search mechanism that could search for the titles of the queries and not the SQL itself. Titles are plain english and there shouldn't be a problem with that. Also, even when I search through Google, I am only looking for a title index, not SQL index per se. Do you really think we *need* a search for the actual text of the queries?

Comment: Well robots.txt is now working: http://odata.stackexchange.com/robots.txt thanks for reporting it.

Comment: @waffles, cool, now searching `site:odata.stackexchange.com` in google give me several thousands of results.

Comment: @waffles is there any intention to add an integrated search box in the data site itself?