# Search on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, data-explorer

Could we please have a search box on SEDE to search the queries?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53545/search-over-queries-needed (requests the ability to search the query *bodies*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I [added](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=2bb492aaea2bd98c75fea301d6a24ae6f964a2ce) the ability to search saved queries.

It's a substring search on both the Title and Description, and you need to put in 2 characters at a minimum. By default, it searches through all the saved queries, but you can add "isfeatured:1" to only search the Featured queries.

(This isn't documented anywhere on the site yet. I just wanted to keep it simple to start with.)