# Add ability to search saved odata queries

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search on Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67660/search-on-stack-exchange-data-explorer)

Am I blind or is there really no way to search the saved queries on odata.stackexchange.com?  There seems to be a lot of cool stuff there but it's hard to find anything in particular just by browsing around.