# Is there a query which shows which user(s) has the most of a specified badge in a specified site?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Or can someone write one?  I *am* rather a stats geek, so I won't be anguished by an answer in the negative, but if it's not too much work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here you go](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/820/who-has-the-most-copies-of-one-badge) -- a while back I [added search to SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67660/search-on-stack-exchange-data-explorer/73427#73427), and it works like a charm. :)

Note: the way that query is written, the badge name you input is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Well [here's my feeble attempt.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/108440/)  Now I'm no SQL guru so I couldn't figure out string parameters, so you have to manually edit which badge you're searching for.