# Add the ability to sort Data Explorer search-query-by-name results by views and by number of favorites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, data-explorer, sorting

When you search for a query in Data Explorer, you are directed to the "recent" tab, the search results are sorted by date (most recent first). If I click on the "popular" tab after the search, I would expect to see results sorted by popularity (views), given that is how regular SE and Meta SE sites work.

But that is not the case in Data Explorer. Once you click on "popular" tab after searching, your search terms simply get discarded and it simply shows *all* queries sorted by views. Same thing happens when you click on any of the 5 tabs after searching.

I can manually construct the sorted query in the URL. For example, the search for query names containing "Jon Skeet", sorted by views would look like this:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular&q=jon+skeet

But this is not currently achievable via searching + clicking on tabs.

Granted I don't really search for queries that often, but the way it works now is kind of counter-intuitive in view of how things work in SE and Meta sites. Plus, being able to sort by popularity is more helpful than sorting by how recent the query is run (such as separating popular queries from their multitudinous forks)

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't really seem like there's any reason to not do this, so [now you'll be able to](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/45), following a pull and redeploy. I simultaneously fixed an issue where anonymous users wouldn't have their page size persisted when switching between those tabs as well. This still doesn't work quite the same way as the Q&A sites, but it's now a little less annoying.

The exception for search is the "everything" tab, which will keep your search parameter but just ignore it. If we get around to [having less terrible search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53545/search-over-queries-needed) then allowing searches to be performed on that tab might make more sense, but for the time being it'll continue to just show you, well, everything.