# keywords search on SEDE might need improvement

Tags: discussion, search, data-explorer

I wrote a query to [list all posts for a given user by user id](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1206756).

```
SELECT id, PostTypeId, posts.Title, Body, CreationDate
FROM posts
WHERE posts.OwnerUserId = 9872
```

which could be found [by search](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/queries?q=list%20all%20posts) the following keywords

> list all posts

nevertheless, I [cannot find that query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/queries?q=list%20all%20posts%20by%20user) by more specific keywords

> list all posts by user

I guess it is **not convenient** for those users might want to find existing queries.

I am not sure if this could be considered as feature request, please correct if necessary.

Comment: _"I am not sure if this could be considered as feature request, please correct if necessary."_ A FR usually needs to be a bit more fleshed out and propose a possible solution. I replaced the tag with [tag:discussion].

Comment: I don't know what's to discuss. It's unexpected behaviour so maybe it should be tagged a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer "search" is pretty naive, if not basic.

This is how your search term is used:

```
builder.Where(@"  qs.Title LIKE @search 
               OR qs.[Description] LIKE @search", 
        new { search = '%' + searchCriteria.SearchTerm + '%' });
```

So it is looking for your search text **as is** in either the title or the description of a query row.

Now that we know how the internal query works, we can use that to our advantage. To find your query we have to strategically add an extra percent in the search term like so:

> [`list all posts%by user`](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/queries?q=list+all+posts%25by+user)

and your query does show up:

[image: search result with one query, the query name list all posts for a given user by user id]

**TL;DR**

SEDE search is not a keyword search at all. It searches for the whole search term if no extra care is given. It does accept % and _ and [A-Z] to refine the search pattern. Applying those can make it into a keyword search.