# What does *description* in query refer to?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

A nice guy @rene gave the answer to [keywords search on SEDE might need improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344746/717233)

```
builder.Where(@"  qs.Title LIKE @search 
               OR qs.[Description] LIKE @search", 
        new { search = '%' + searchCriteria.SearchTerm + '%' });
```

> So it is looking for your search text as is in either the title or the **description** of a query row.

take the query [word count a user](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1206589/word-count-a-user?UserId=9872) as example, does *description* refer to the part pointed out by red rectangle in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, have a close look when creating a query:

[image: title and query window]

Click the link *edit description*

The textbox for the description is revealed:

[image: query window with title and description box visible]

Don't forget to "Run" your query once you edited the Title and/or Description as that is the only way to trigger an insert/update to the database.